# New pointer (by malloc) is same as one of the freed/old pointers

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

I am trying to track use-after-free errors in C.
And my question is that, if I have the code like this:

```
A * ptrA = malloc(sizeof(A));
A * aliasA = ptrA;
// do something ' 
free(ptrA) 
// some other code
B * ptrB = malloc(sizeof(B)); // assume this return same pointer as ptrA
//trying to use aliasA here
```

Just wondering if the use of aliasA is a UAF error?
If it is, what is going wrong here?

To clear the question, I think it is better to add a small example:

```
int main(){
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(4);
    *ptr = 5;
    int *ptr2 = ptr;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    free(ptr);

    int *new_ptr = malloc(4);
    *new_ptr = 66;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
5
66
```

(I checked `ptr` and `new_ptr` in S2E: http://s2e.systems/ and these two pointers actually point to the same address. After freeing ptr, the same address is allocated to new_ptr.)

From the output above, it seems like the use of `ptr2` gives the same output as `new_ptr`.

When I wrote my solution to detect UAF error, I record the information of pointers. The pointers' values are stored as `uint64_t` and a boolean type `flag` is to declare whether the pointer is alive.

Therefore, I guess a problem occurs when the `new_ptr` and `ptr` point to same address because once `malloc()` is called the `flag` for `new_ptr` will turn `true`. After that, when I use `ptr`, I can not detect this UAF error because this address is marked alive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have reason to suspect that `malloc` will return the same address twice?

Comment: You can't assume anything about the behavior of malloc other than you ask for a pointer to a block of a certain size, and assuming no error, you get a pointer to a block of at least the size you asked for.

Comment: what is UAF error?

Comment: @coderredoc Use After Free.This is new to me.

Comment: Yes, it's a UAF error. No it doesn't matter if `malloc` returns the same address again (which it's allowed to do), you still use a pointer you shouldn't.

Comment: "//trying to use aliasA here" How will you use it? If you dereference it (`*aliasA`), it is undefined behavior - see for instance http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3p.html where it is stated very clear. However, you can of cause use the pointer for other thing but a direct dereferencing... no. It makes absolutely no difference whether or not the two malloc returns the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't *dereference* the pointer `aliasA`, it depends on the definition of "use after free" whether this constitutes "use after free". For example [CWE-416](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html) doesn't talk about just *using* the pointer value, but about dereferencing it, i.e. using the *object* that was freed.

However, the C standard says that even **using** the pointer value has undefined behaviour [(Appendix J.2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> 1. The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
>    [...]
>
>    - The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used (7.22.3).

This is because the [value of the pointer becomes *indeterminate*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2):

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Therefore the following code has undefined behaviour:

```
A *ptrA = malloc(sizeof(A));
A *aliasA = ptrA;
free(ptrA);
A *ptrB = malloc(sizeof(A));

if (aliasA == ptrB) { // undefined behaviour, as it might be a trap
    printf("We were given the same pointer");
}
```

The comparison there is meaningless and the compiler is given the freedom to do whatever it pleases with its optimization, as `aliasA` doesn't need to contain a *valid* value any more. It is totally OK for a compiler to even to set a trap into `aliasA` which would cause your program to abort at the `if` statement with a diagnostics message. Or it can be that these could seem to point to the same address even though they were given distinct addresses of memory, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

This ***is*** a UAF error.

In practice, it is *very* unlikely that the second `malloc()` call returns the same address as `aliasA`, as the behavior is not guaranteed. You should not rely on it.

You may ask: *Can I compare them to make sure they have the same address?* Well, no. Comparing may make some sense to you, but it is undefined behavior, because pointer equality comparison is valid only if the two pointers point to different elements in the same array. In this case the two allocated blocks surely aren't the same array, so comparison between those pointers isn't well-defined.

At last, you shouldn't rely on the address returned by `malloc()`. All you can do is use it within the amount of memory requested when calling.

In practice, [*Thiru Shetty*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900044/5958455) is a good way to pursue.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. Pointer **equality** is defined anywhere - otherwise the comparison against i.e. NULL would not be right. This is UB simply because the previous pointer refers to an object whose lifetime has ended, and its value is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

The `aliasA` is UAF error, it may hold the same value as `ptrA` but it's not guaranteed and it's recommended to re-assign the freed pointer (both aliasA and ptrA) to `NULL` to avoid [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

In your case, it's better to assign `NULL` after you `free`:

```
free(ptrA);
free(aliasA);
ptrA = NULL;
aliasA = NULL;
```

Comment: ***dereference*** and ***assignment*** are two different things :)

Comment: Comment is not a good place to add information. You should [edit] it into your answer :)

Comment: I don't understand why it's negative vote even after correction ?? Is not going to help someone ?? is that seriously negative ??

Comment: NMDV, yet`A * aliasA = ptrA;` occurs before the `free(ptrA)` so "The `aliasA` is UAF error" is unclear.  Even worse `A * aliasA = ptrA; free(ptrA);
free(aliasA);` is a UAF error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, basically,  I make this code on purpose because I expected that an error message should be emitted..